# Calling all methods define on single aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Title might me some how confusing.. So let me explain my requirement.

I want to check my services which have been consumed by my website is up and running.
For this I am creating **aspx** page with different method that will call each service method to check service is up and running.

Now the Req is :  I don't want to call all these method on my page load event but instead of that I want when page load it automatically call each and every method define on that page.

These method will write there respective response on page using Response.Write

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection for this:

```
public partial class Reflection : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        foreach(MethodInfo info in type.GetMethods())
        {
            if (info.Name.StartsWith("DoStuff"))
                info.Invoke(this,null);
        }
    }

    public void DoStuff1()
    {
        Response.Write("DoStuff1<br />");
    }

    public void DoStuff2()
    {
        Response.Write("DoStuff2<br />");
    }

    public void DoStuff3()
    {
        Response.Write("DoStuff3<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Denis I have posted code snippet. let me know if you have any idea of the issue I am facing.. thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have any methods that start with "DoStuff" in your code.That's why it doesn't work

Comment: It still not worked as expected. Now with the above code it is working only once on first page load not after we refresh that page.